# Implicit conversion of both operands for operator==

Tags: c++

The following code compiles and executed without error even though no equality operator is defined:

```
class A {
public:
    operator bool() const { return true; }
};


int main()
{
    A a, b;
    a == b; //why does this compile?
    return 0;
}
```

What happens internally for `a == b` is that the `operator bool() const` is called for **both** operands, and then the two booleans are compared for equality (this happened in our production code where `class A` was a smart pointer type, and gave semantically dubious results).

My question is: What rule in the C++ standard allows for the implicit conversion of **both** operands in this case? I can understand that **one** operand would be implicitly converted to `bool` for the test for equality **if** the other operand was already a `bool`, but not both.

Comment: What makes you understand that? Have you ever followed the guideline for adding `operator==` to a class? It is suggested to make it a friend free function that accepts two class objects by a const reference. This is precisely to allow for implicit type conversions of **both** operands.

Comment: @StoryTeller You could interpret the same reasoning to mean it allows conversion of **either** operand, and not necessarily expect it will apply to both simultaneously. And if you haven't fully got your head around normal lookup and ADL, I could see why you would expect that.

Comment: @BoBTFish - You can interpret a guideline to achieve something as somehow not achieving it?

Comment: @StoryTeller No, I mean you may have been told the guideline, but not been told or fully understand the complete reasoning. I'm saying I don't find it too surprising that the asker understood it differently to your description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can understand that one operand would be implicitly converted ..., but not both

Then you've misunderstood. EDIT: According to the experts in comments, argument dependent lookup appears to be a case where your assumption is correct. But yours isn't a case of ADL.

> What rule in the C++ standard allows for the implicit conversion of both operands

From standard draft:

> [over.match] (2.9)
>
> - Then the best viable function is selected based on the implicit conversion sequences (13.3.3.1) needed
>   to match **each argument** to the corresponding parameter of each viable function.

My emphasis on "each argument". Not "a single argument".

Comment: This is when the operator to be called is found during normal lookup, right? It couldn't be found via ADL unless one of the arguments was already the same as the parameter type?

Comment: @BoBTFish - correct. That's why `operator==` for `std::string` won't be used to compare two raw character pointers.

Comment: @StoryTeller Isn't the reason for that the fact that there is a built in operator, that does not require any conversions so it is preferred?

Comment: @user2079303 - It doesn't have to be built-in. You can construct an example with user defined types. But you are correct that the reason is mostly due to a much better match being present.

Comment: @BoBTFish & StoryTeller I hadn't come across the difference that ADL has on this. I find the rules on ADL to be too confusing, so I'll take your word for it.

Comment: @user2079303: just to make sure I understand your answer correctly: overload resolution considers `static bool operator(bool, bool)` as a candidate function for my `a==b` comparison, because it essentially just ignores the parameter types at *this stage*. And after the list of of candidate functions is completed, the compiler determines that by applying the implicit conversion rules to the two variables of type `A`, those can be converted to `bool` so that `static bool operator(bool, bool)` can be called? Is that what's happening

Comment: @Dreamer Pretty much so.